# vba code copy multiple excel charts to word

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the VBA code [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=133#instr) to copy all the charts and tables from an excel workbook into a new word document from a template which is pre-formatted with bookmarks (labeled Book1, Book2 etc). Unfortunately i only have a few tables but around 20 charts and if i leave a blank in the summary table for the ranges i get

> Run-time error '5101':
>   Application-defined or object defined error

and it only copies and pastes over the charts and table before the gap.

This is my excel summary table:

[image]

Any idea how i can modify the code to prevent this?

Sorry - i'm a complete VBA noob

```
'You must set a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library from Tools | References

Option Explicit 

Sub ExportToWord() 

    Dim appWrd          As Object 
    Dim objDoc          As Object 
    Dim FilePath        As String 
    Dim FileName        As String 
    Dim x               As Long 
    Dim LastRow         As Long 
    Dim SheetChart      As String 
    Dim SheetRange      As String 
    Dim BookMarkChart   As String 
    Dim BookMarkRange   As String 
    Dim Prompt          As String 
    Dim Title           As String 

     'Turn some stuff off while the macro is running
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.EnableEvents = False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

     'Assign the Word file path and name to variables
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path 
    FileName = "WorkWithExcel.doc" 

     'Determine the last row of data for our loop
    LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 

     'Create an instance of Word for us to use
    Set appWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application") 

     'Open our specified Word file, On Error is used in case the file is not there
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set objDoc = appWrd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName) 
    On Error Goto 0 

     'If the file is not found, we need to end the sub and let the user know
    If objDoc Is Nothing Then 
        MsgBox "Unable to find the Word file.", vbCritical, "File Not Found" 
        appWrd.Quit 
        Set appWrd = Nothing 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 

     'Copy/Paste Loop starts here
    For x = 2 To LastRow 

         'Use the Status Bar to let the user know what the current progress is
        Prompt = "Copying Data: " & x - 1 & " of " & LastRow - 1 & "   (" & _ 
        Format((x - 1) / (LastRow - 1), "Percent") & ")" 
        Application.StatusBar = Prompt 

         'Assign the worksheet names and bookmark names to a variable
         'Use With to group these lines together
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary") 
            SheetChart = .Range("A" & x).Text 
            SheetRange = .Range("B" & x).Text 
            BookMarkChart = .Range("C" & x).Text 
            BookMarkRange = .Range("D" & x).Text 
        End With 

         'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkRange
        appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkRange 

         'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetRange).UsedRange.Copy 

         'Paste into Word
        appWrd.Selection.Paste 

         'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkChart
        appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkChart 

         'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetChart).ChartObjects(1).Copy 

         'Paste into Word
        appWrd.Selection.Paste 
    Next 

     'Turn everything back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.EnableEvents = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
    Application.StatusBar = False 

     'Let the user know the procedure is now complete
    Prompt = "The procedure is now completed." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "www.VBAExpress.com" 
    Title = "Procedure Completion" 
    MsgBox Prompt, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title 

     'Make our Word session visible
    appWrd.Visible = True 

     'Clean up
    Set appWrd = Nothing 
    Set objDoc = Nothing 

End Sub
```

full working code is below. I've modified the code so it pastes charts as enhanched metafiles because that's what my boss wants.

```
    'You must set a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library from Tools | References

Option Explicit

Sub ExportToWord()

Dim appWrd          As Object
Dim objDoc          As Object
Dim FilePath        As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim x               As Long
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim SheetChart      As String
Dim SheetRange      As String
Dim BookMarkChart   As String
Dim BookMarkRange   As String
Dim Prompt          As String
Dim Title           As String

    'Turn some stuff off while the macro is running
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Assign the Word file path and name to variables
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    FileName = "WorkWithExcel.doc"

    'Determine the last row of data for our loop
    LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Create an instance of Word for us to use
    Set appWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Open our specified Word file, On Error is used in case the file is not there
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objDoc = appWrd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If the file is not found, we need to end the sub and let the user know
    If objDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find the Word file.", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
        appWrd.Quit
        Set appWrd = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Copy/Paste Loop starts here
    For x = 2 To LastRow

        'Use the Status Bar to let the user know what the current progress is
        Prompt = "Copying Data: " & x - 1 & " of " & LastRow - 1 & "   (" & _
            Format((x - 1) / (LastRow - 1), "Percent") & ")"
        Application.StatusBar = Prompt

        'Assign the worksheet names and bookmark names to a variable
        'Use With to group these lines together
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
            SheetChart = .Range("A" & x).Text
            SheetRange = .Range("B" & x).Text
            BookMarkChart = .Range("C" & x).Text
            BookMarkRange = .Range("D" & x).Text
        End With

If Len(BookMarkRange) > 0 Then

'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkRange
appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkRange

'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetRange).UsedRange.Copy

'Paste into Word
appWrd.Selection.Paste
End If

If Len(BookMarkChart) > 0 Then

'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkChart
appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkChart

'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetChart).ChartObjects(1).Copy

'Paste into Word
'appWrd.Selection.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
 appWrd.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

End If

    Next

    'Turn everything back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

    'Let the user know the procedure is now complete
    Prompt = "The procedure is now completed." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "www.VBAExpress.com"
    Title = "Procedure Completion"
    MsgBox Prompt, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title

    'Make our Word session visible
    appWrd.Visible = True

    'Clean up
    Set appWrd = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This will not fix your main problem but I'd advise using this to find Last Row instead of your current code: `LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` since 65536 is not the last row in newer versions of excel.

Comment: thanks i'll add it to the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code, including the fact that if you had more ranges than charts it would only copy as many ranges as there was charts.

But to quickly fix your problem, replace

```
 'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkRange
appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkRange 

 'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetRange).UsedRange.Copy 

 'Paste into Word
appWrd.Selection.Paste 

 'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkChart
appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkChart 

 'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetChart).ChartObjects(1).Copy 

 'Paste into Word
appWrd.Selection.Paste
```

with

```
if len (BookMarkRange) > 0 then
   'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkRange
  appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkRange 

   'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetRange).UsedRange.Copy 

   'Paste into Word
  appWrd.Selection.Paste 
end if

if len(BookMarkChart) > 0 then
   'Tell Word to goto the bookmark assigned to the variable BookMarkChart
  appWrd.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkChart 

   'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetChart).ChartObjects(1).Copy 

   'Paste into Word
  appWrd.Selection.Paste 
end if
```

Comment: thanks @GSerg for the help and the format edits - it now crashes at 'Copy the data from Thisworkbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetChart).ChartObjects(1).Copy with  runtime error 9 - subscript out of range.

Comment: @j_hindsight That would mean you set up a bookmark name for a chart, but did not provide a sheet name for the chart (or misspelled it).

Comment: YES! one of the bookmarks was playing up in word. Thanks for all your help - means i can actually get some work done rather than spend all day copying and pasting ;-)